# GET request Flex / Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

Struggling to find any documentation to do a simple GET request to a URL to return JSON in Actionscript / Flex.

Anyone know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [**URLLoader**](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html) API.

```
var myJSON :Object; //listing as per "key:" with "value"
var str_JSON: String = ""; //if you need text String not data Object

var siteloader :URLLoader = new URLLoader( new URLRequest( your_URL ) );

siteloader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, whenSiteLoaded);

function whenSiteLoaded( evt :Event ) :void 
{
  myJSON = JSON.parse(evt.target.data); //get into Object
  str_JSON = evt.target.data; //get into String
  //... any other code
}
```

You should add to the above the listeners for error conditions (eg: a *"file not found"* situation)

Comment: Hope you don't mind the edit. It's not clear if the asker wants result as text (String) or as actual Object of parsed JSON.

Comment: @vc No problem. Thanks for the improvements.